# Does struct.pack(f'{len(x)}s', x) do anything at all?

Tags: python, c, struct, struct.pack

Consider the following code:

```python
import struct

x = b'example' # can be any bytes object
y = struct.pack(f'{len(x)}s', x)
print(x == y)
```

If I understand [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/struct.html#format-characters) correctly, the function call will return the binary representation of a struct that has an array of `len(x)` `char`s (that contains the contents of `x`) as its only member. Is there any circumstance under which this will not just be `x` itself?

Or, to rephrase this question to the C perspective (since I also tagged this question that), does the C standard allow for more than one binary representation of `struct MyStruct { char s[MY_SIZE]; };`?

I am asking this because [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#app_side) is instructing me to do just that (Ctrl + F for “Python 3”):

```python
# Encode a message for transmission, given its content.
def encode_message(message_content):
    encoded_content = json.dumps(message_content).encode("utf-8")
    encoded_length = struct.pack('=I', len(encoded_content))
    #  use struct.pack("10s", bytes), to pack a string of the length of 10 characters
    return {'length': encoded_length, 'content': struct.pack(str(len(encoded_content))+"s",encoded_content)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about Python. In C, `unsigned char [N]` has exactly one binary representation, but `char[N]` *might* have padding bits within each `char`, and `struct { anything; }` can have padding at the end. The extent to which Python's `struct` library implements these edge cases is one of the things I'm not sure of.

Comment: @zw I tried all possible `bytes` up to length 3, then 1000 random ones of length 1 million, then 1000 random ones for each length up to 1000. In all cases, the struct packing had no effect.

Comment: In C, structure padding does not need to come only at the end, it can come between any members with unlike alignment requirements.

Comment: @zwol If the `struct` library didn’t do exactly what the system’s C compiler is doing, that would be kind of self-defeating. I think you’re wrong about padding bits inside `char` ([check this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Object_representation)). Also, since `alignof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment)), I don’t see how we could end up with padding at the end of the struct.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes, but there cannot be padding at the _beginning_ of a `struct` (so a struct with one member can have padding _only_ at the end) and there cannot be padding in between the elements of an array.

Comment: @Ground (1) cppreference.com is not authoritative; assuming `char` is signed, I don't see anything in [section 6.2.6.1 or 6.2.6.2 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6) that says it can't have padding bits. I will acknowledge that this is extremely unlikely, however.  (2) `struct { char x; }` does not have to have the same alignment requirement as `char x`; there have been ABIs that said the minimum alignment for _all_ `struct` types was 4, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely pointless. Whoever wrote that example probably didn't think it through or didn't quite understand what `struct.pack` does.

Particularly, even if you had an utterly bizarre platform that would actually pad `struct MyStruct { char s[MY_SIZE]; };`, the Python `struct` module still wouldn't pad that `struct.pack` call. `struct.pack` doesn't add trailing padding (or leading padding, if you had some *really* weird platform that would do that). Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-alignment):

> Padding is only automatically added between successive structure members. No padding is added at the beginning or the end of the encoded struct.